# Remove first and Last character from string In Formula field

Tags: formula-field, string

My output in formula field is : `[ ref:_5540058J._578sdie5:ref ]`

My expected output is :

```
ref:_5540058J._578sdie5:ref
```

I tried Trim with Left and Right but it is not giving expected result

Comment: when you tried trim what did you get.

Comment: I got it by using Mid and length functions ->  MID( field__c , 2, LEN(field__c) -2 )

Answer (score 1):

Try below function

```
TRIM(
    LEFT(
        TRIM(
            RIGHT(field__c,  (LEN(field__c) - 1) ) 
        ),
        (LEN(field__c) - 3)
    )
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Following function will also work

```
TRIM(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(field__c,'[',''),']',''))
```